# multiple progress of "Refreshing Compose Preview .. " always stay in the bottom bar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

Since I am trying jetpack compose, the following progresses always stays there.. they are not doing any harm. but pressing the close does not close them.

[image]

and

[image]

Any suggestion?

Comment: hey man did anyone found a solution to this?